# Tailwind of version 2.2.8 generates the class that breaks all styles declared after it

Tags: tailwind-css

This is how the class looks like

```
.w-\[this-is\\\\\]w-\\\\\[weird-but-valid\] {
     width: this-is\\]w-\\[weird-but-valid;
}
```

When I remove this class, the styles apply fine. I don't understand where this class comes from. When I searched for tailwind package I only found this class name in the comments.

Comment: Ok, I just installed tailwindcss of 2.2.7 version. And that problem is gone

Comment: I had exactly the same problem with Tailwindcss V3.0.23. But why it has not been resolved yet?